# How do I secure API endpoints in a microservice architecture in Swing Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, microservices

I'm still a beginner in the field of micro services and I'm currently sitting on a problem that I don't know how to resolve.

Picture this:
I have a product service, which has an endpoint to add stock to it. The problem it, anyone can send a request to this endpoint and it will work.

I also have a user service, that can register and authenticate users using JWT. The user has either the role USER or ADMIN.

I want the product service to check if the authenticated user has the role ADMIN, and if yes, to accept the response, else respond with 403. How could I achieve this?

I have thought about connecting both using rabbitmq:

- I send the JWT token to the user service
- the user service checks if the token is valid
- if yes, it returns the role to the product service

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my example implementation:

1. Create an AuthenticationFilter, which extends GenericFilter. In this filter, it will extract JWT from request (from header, cookie, or query param)

```java
@Component
public class AuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
}
```

2. Then, you can call to your `user-service` to verify the JWT
3. If the JWT is unvalid, then throw `UnauthorizeException`
4. If the JWT is valid, then put the Authentication object in the SecurityContext:

```java
// principal and authorities should be extracted from JWT or retrieved from response from userservice when validate JWT
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principalFromJwt, null, List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"))); 
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

5. Add the created filter to configuration of spring

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            ... // Some other security configs

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! The security is already working in the user service but I need to secure the product service.

Comment: @JesséMonguar The solution above will secure your product service (or any other microservice). It calls userservice for checking JWT token or user identity only because the product service does not know about token/user data

Comment: The solution above should be implemented inside product service fyi